# Selecting Item from Database loaded DropDownList and displaying data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a drop down list loaded from the database and I want to display data based on specific items in the drop down list. In the where clause it compares the drop down list with the selected item and displays all the information for that event.

Also I have an exception on the @Html.DropDownList("RaceEvent);

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The ViewData item that has the key 'RaceEvent' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

The controller looks like this

```
private raceEntities db = new raceEntities();
    // GET: Registrants
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var regist = new SelectList(db.raceevents, "RaceEventID", "Name").ToString();

        ViewBag.RaceEvent = regist;

        /* iterate through raceevent table grab Name column convert to string
        var qry = (from rac in db.raceevents
                  select new { rac.Name }).ToString();
        */

        var registrants = (from per in db.people
                           join personorgrole in db.personorganizationroles on per.PersonID equals personorgrole.PersonID
                           join personeve in db.personevents on personorgrole.PersonOrganizationRoleID equals personeve.PersonOrganizationRoleID
                           join eventcla in db.eventclasses on personeve.RaceEventID equals eventcla.RaceEventID
                           join personeventcla in db.personeventclasses on eventcla.EventClassID equals personeventcla.EventClassID
                           join raceeve in db.raceevents on eventcla.RaceEventID equals raceeve.RaceEventID
                           join organizationrolety in db.organizationroletypes on personorgrole.OrganizationRoleTypeID equals organizationrolety.OrganizationRoleTypeID
                           //where raceeve.Name == "Ruapehu Gravity Festival"
                           where raceeve.Name == regist  //raceeve.Name matches the selectlist above 
                          // where raceeve.Name == qry //compare event name with the query above
                           select new Registrants { LastName = per.LastName, FirstName = per.FirstName, RoleType = organizationrolety.Name }).Distinct().OrderBy( per => per.LastName);

        return View(registrants);
    }
```

The view looks like this

```
@model IEnumerable<IDFWebApp.Models.Custom.Registrants>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Event Registrants";
}

<h2>Event Registrants</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.DropDownList("RaceEvent") //references from ViewBag.RaceEvent in the controller

<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Role Type</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var person in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@person.LastName</td>
            <td>@person.FirstName</td>
            <td>@person.RoleType</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Drop down list fix only. You could probably do an ajax call in a script element and populate a div passing down the Id of the selected SelectListItem.

It would be best to create a view model.

```
public class RegistrantsViewModel
{
    public RegistrantsViewModel()
    {
        RaceEvents = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<IDFWebApp.Models.Custom.Registrants> Registrants { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> RaceEvents { get; set; }

    public Int32 SelectedItem { get; set; }

}
```

Controller

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Create a new view model.
        RegistrantsViewModel oViewModel = new RegistrantsViewModel();

        //Pull back all events from the datasource.
        IEnumerable<RaceEvent> lAllRaceEvents = db.raceevents;

        //Iterate over every event.
        foreach (RaceEvent lEvent in lAllRaceEvents)
        {
            //Map each event to a select list item and attach it to the view model.
            oViewModel.RaceEvents.Add(new SelectListItem{ Text = lEvent.EventName, Value = lEvent.Id });
        }

        //iterate through raceevent table grab Name column convert to string
        //Also attach to the view model.
        oViewModel.Registrants = (from per in db.people
                                   join personorgrole in db.personorganizationroles on per.PersonID equals personorgrole.PersonID
                                   join personeve in db.personevents on personorgrole.PersonOrganizationRoleID equals personeve.PersonOrganizationRoleID
                                   join eventcla in db.eventclasses on personeve.RaceEventID equals eventcla.RaceEventID
                                   join personeventcla in db.personeventclasses on eventcla.EventClassID equals personeventcla.EventClassID
                                   join raceeve in db.raceevents on eventcla.RaceEventID equals raceeve.RaceEventID
                                   join organizationrolety in db.organizationroletypes on personorgrole.OrganizationRoleTypeID equals organizationrolety.OrganizationRoleTypeID
                                   //where raceeve.Name == "Ruapehu Gravity Festival"
                                   where raceeve.Name == regist  //raceeve.Name matches the selectlist above 
                                   // where raceeve.Name == qry //compare event name with the query above
                                   select new Registrants { LastName = per.LastName, FirstName = per.FirstName, RoleType = organizationrolety.Name }).Distinct().OrderBy(per => per.LastName);

        return View(oViewModel);
    }
```

View

```
//Namespace where to find your view model. App specific.
@model IDFWebApp.Models.Custom.RegistrantsViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Event Registrants";
}

<h2>Event Registrants</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.SelectedItem, Model.RaceEvents, "-- Pick a race event")

    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Role Type</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var person in Model.Registrants) //Forgot sub property (facepalm)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@person.LastName</td>
                <td>@person.FirstName</td>
                <td>@person.RoleType</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `.ToString();` from `var regist = new SelectList(db.raceevents, "RaceEventID", "Name").ToString();`

When using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492948(v=vs.118).aspx) of `@Html.DropdownList()`, where you specify the name of the form field, the value must be `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` (which `SelectList` is), but you are converting it to a string with the value `"System.Web.MVC.SelectList"`, so it needs to be

```
var regist = new SelectList(db.raceevents, "RaceEventID", "Name");
```